# Ordering of reflection requests in dotnet

Tags: c#, .net

When I call GetProperties() on a type, the properties are ordered as they are written in the source code. This is very handy but my question is, if this is a guaranteed behavior or may this change depending on the runtime version and the environment.  Does anyone know something about that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, you can't assume the order will stay the same.

Quote from the [doc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kyaxdd3x.aspx):

*The GetProperties  method does not return properties in a particular order, such as alphabetical or declaration order. Your code must not depend on the order in which properties are returned, because that order varies.*