# Assembly ordering in .net c#

Tags: c#, reflection, enumeration

A similar question has been asked in [Ordering of reflection requests in dotnet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3035989/ordering-of-reflection-requests-in-dotnet)
But I'm hoping for a different answer... I'm writing a plugin for a program that uses reflection to interrogate plugins to find the entry point. Unfortunately it has a bug which means if it encounters an interface declaration during this process it crashes with an unhandled exception. I have spoken to the development team and this is unlikely to be fixed. This is extremely limiting for me for obvious reasons. One workaround I have already thought of is to have my assembly load another assembly with the interfaces in it, but for reasons I won't go into this is not a great solution. It was a while before I encountered this problem because for some reason my entry class always preceded my interfaces in the reflection enumeration order.

My question is, is there any way to influence the ordering of classes and interfaces in the assembly?

Note: I have already tried setting different accessibility levels on my interfaces but that doesn't work for me.
Cheers,
J

Comment: " I have spoken to the development team and this is unlikely to be fixed" - Why? Sounds like it needs fixing to me! Just tell them to fix it! If you don't fix this, you are treating the symptoms and not the cause.

Comment: Are you sure it's a bug in the framework, or are you accessing members on `Type` that are not applicable to interfaces? I've written similar assembly-walking code for a plug-in system of my own, and have not encountered any such problem.

Comment: @Bradley He doesn't apparently own the assembly-walking code… That's why he's looking for a workaround.

Comment: You should tell them to fix that code, me too have written a plugin system loading classes and interfaces from external asemblies and is working fine. So you should solve the root cause, not the symptoms

Comment: @Ondrej Tucny: The poster may not "own the assembly-walking code" but it states he has talked to the dev team.

Comment: @Jack, IMO, one assembly loading other assemblies seems to be good workaround (and probably the one one)!

Comment: @Mitch Wheat: Doesn't mean anything — the dev team may be disconnected, with a rigid dev-cycle, the version of the code may be outdated, etc.

Comment: @Ondrej Tucny: it does mean something. It means the code is actively being developed. That means it can be actively fixed! :)

Comment: @Mitch: Well, yes, unless Jack is using some outdated branch which is excluded from maintenance — that was my point :-)

Comment: Yeah unfortunately I don't own the code and the dev team is changing their API's due to be released in 2012 but of course I must continue to work with the existing API.  In a perfect world they'd fix this for me because I'm sure an if statement is all that is required...  E.g. if the thing is a class then do class type things... Don't just assume because it looks like a class it is a class because sometimes it's an interface.... Ah well it's not a perfect world.  Anyway some of the most interesting language features are learn't whilst trying to workaround legacy code!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd bet the code using `AppDomain.GetAssemblies()` which are then inspected. The implementation of `AppDomain.GetAssemblies()` leads to an external method, so Reflector is of mostly no help here.

However, without actually trying it and inspecting the result, there are two logical options for the ordering of assemblies in the result:

1. Load order
2. Alphabetical order

In the first case you'd probably have to organize references among your assemblies and the load order in such a way that the foreign code finds the right assembly with the entrypoint class and stops. In the second case it would be a pure matter of naming the assemblies in a 'right' way but I doubt it's this case.

*(However, the order may be completely different from the two above, e.g. 'mostly' random as well.)*

In either case I think sooner or later the buggy code will encounter the problematic assembly and crash anyway. Thus the strong recommendation is: **insist on having the bug fixed.**

Comment: +1 from me, especially for the bit that says "insist on having the bug fixed.
" !

Comment: Thanks for this however it's not the ordering of assemblies but the ordering of classes/interfaces in the assembly that I need to influence.  Sometimes (and I don't know why) the compiler will put my Main class before my interfaces, sometimes an interface comes first...